the Winfall lottery math
This video:
Jerry and Marge Go Large: 60 Minutes' original story on the Selbees' lottery loophole

One day, while at the local gas station, Jerry overhears a conversation about the WinFall lottery's rolldown weeks. A mathematician at heart, he quickly figures out a statistical loophole. He realizes that during rolldowns, buying a large number of tickets almost guarantees a win.

Dude ended up winning $ 8 million in almost guaranteed lottery winnings.
Can someone please explain the math involved here? It can't be simple or the lottery designers would have caught it.

The word "almost" is doing a lot of heavy-lifting in this question. What do you mean by the qualifier "almost" here?

Isn’t it the story where a random advertising team decided to (temporarily) halve the price of a ticket for a certain lottery, and didn’t realize that it made playing net positive in expectation (contrary to the point of any self-respecting lottery)?

I'm not sure whether it was this particular lottery, or another one with a similar construction, but the lottery operators were informed of the situation – and they didn't care! As long as the money was rolling in, it didn't matter to them who was winning how much.

Here's a story about it: https://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2016/02/how-mit-students-gamed-the-lottery/470349/ Here's another: https://newsfeed.time.com/2012/08/07/how-mit-students-scammed-the-massachusetts-lottery-for-8-million/ and here: https://alum.mit.edu/slice/calculated-approach-winning-lottery

Jordan Ellenberg has a chapter about the math in his book, How Not To Be Wrong. You can listen to a lecture he gave, at https://maa.org/meetings/calendar-events/how-to-get-rich-playing-the-lottery

Here's a paper which goes into the details.

The lottery expects X in ticket sales and Y in price money. If Y > X then your expectation of winning is high. It seems the lottery has rules where in sum weeks Y > X. If you know that, then you bet nothing in the weeks with low payout, and you bet a lot in weeks with high payouts.

You don't just bet a lot – you buy enough tickets to cover every possible set of winning numbers, so you are guaranteed to win.
